# Back tracing parents/paths of two-column data of a tree

Tags: r, igraph

I have a tree data serialized like the following: 
Relationship: P to C is "one-to-many", and C to P is "one-to-one". So column P may have duplicate values, but column C has unique values.

```
P, C
1, 2
1, 3
3, 4
2, 5
4, 6
# in data.frame
df <- data.frame(P=c(1,1,3,2,4), C=c(2,3,4,5,6))
```

**1. How do I efficiently implement a function `func` so that:**

`func(df, val)` returns a vector of full path to root (1 in this case).

For example:

```
func(df, 3) returns c(1,2,3)
func(df, 5)  returns c(1,2,5)
func(df, 6) returns c(1,3,4,6)
```

**2. Alternatively, quickly transforming `df` to a lookup table like this also works for me:**

```
C, Paths
2, c(1,2)
3, c(1,3)
4, c(1,3,4)
5, c(1,2,5)
6, c(1,2,4,6)
```

Comment: Read about igraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
df <- within(df,
             Path <- sapply(match(as.character(C),names(V(g))), 
                            function(k) toString(names(unlist(all_simple_paths(g,1,k))))))
```

such that

```
> df
  P C       Path
1 1 2       1, 2
2 1 3       1, 3
3 3 4    1, 3, 4
4 2 5    1, 2, 5
5 4 6 1, 3, 4, 6
```